# Wrong type return in Resolver does not trigger error

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am building a sever with Graphql. I define a single query which should return a User type. However, in my resolver I am actually returning a string type: "Hello!".

The query executes in the playground without any problem.

My question: the return statement of the resolver expects a User type, instead returns a string. Why is it not failing?

**TypeDef**

```
  type User {
    id: String
    email: String
    name: String
  }

  type Query {
    printUser: User
  }
```

**Resolver**

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    printUser: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      return 'Hello!';
    }
  }
```

[image: RESOLVER PLAYGROUND]

Comment: All alltributes of the type user are marked as optional. Therefore you don't get an error as none of them is required. Try marking the return type of printUser as required (!)